# iOS inheriting a class with a protocol

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

So I have a class called "DrawOnImageViewController", which does something pretty obvious.  In it's header file, I also have a protocol "DrawOnImageDelegate" defined with a single method:  "imageWithDrawingSelected:(UIImage *)image".  This class also obviously has a "delegate" property that conforms to that protocol.

Now I need to subclass this class so I can simply call that delegate method on the delegate in viewWillDisappear.  I subclassed the above class and then overrode viewWillDisappear like so:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.delegate imageWithDrawingSelected:self.imageView.image];
}
```

This method (viewWillDisappear) executes, but my delegate's delegate method is never called.
I tried calling:     [super.delegate imageWithDrawingSelected:super.imageView.image];

But that doesn't work either....

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that `self.delegate` is non-nil at this point?

Comment: @HackyStack Well, messaging `nil` doesn't crash, Objective-C ain't Java.

Comment: Why is it null?  I set the delegate property on this subclass when I instantiate it....

Comment: Check if when you are creating an object of this subclass, you are setting that object.delegate = anotherobject; If that is done, it shouldnt return nil for delegate. If that is not the case, then make sure you are not setting self.delegate = nil anywhere else in the class by mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot.  It's presented in a popover controller, and it was the popover delegate I set, not the subclass.  Sorry, I got it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you have overrided the - init function. please post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an oversight of the most obvious and common kind.  I failed to set the delegate property.  I'll go hang my head in shame...

It's presented in a popover controller, for which the delegate was set, but not the content view controller...

Comment: We all make mistakes, not to worry! :)

Comment: Good advice for the future: if something simple doesn't work, have a sleep and you'll be able to figure out tomorrow :)